# SQL Server QODBC linked server to QuickBooks keeps showing dozens of duplicate empty databases?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, quickbooks, qodbc

I have a SQL Server Express installed locally on my computer that I'm trying to (stably) connect to a local QuickBooks Enterprise file using QODBC. (Yes the SDK is a better option but we're still running 32bit Quickbooks and all our other programs are 64bit, so I'm waiting till the company moves to the 64 bit QB 2023 version.)

The DSN works when tested, and the QRemote server works correctly. Every component works when tested individually, and sometimes I can get the Quickbooks file to successfully show up in the SQL server's linked server objects, but lately the quickbooks file has been showing up as about 50 or so duplicate databases. All are simply named QODBC and are completely empty.

I've noticed if I wait about 15 or 20 minutes the correct database object may show up if I refresh the server, but it can also revert back just as easily. I can't seem to find any other topics related to this so if anyone has any advice, or just knows what's going wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, refreshing the catalog should fix the issue.
To list the tables, you may also use 'sp_tables'

select * from openquery(QRemote,'sp_tables')

To view the table schema or query the table, you can use the following SQL statements.

select * from openquery(QRemote,'sp_columns customer')

select * from openquery(QRemote,'select * from customer')

If you are still facing the issue, please raise a support ticket at https://support.qodbc.com